# AWS: "eb deploy my-env" giving ERROR: ServiceError - 1 validation error detected..Member must have length less than or equal to 100

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

When doing eb deploy no matter the name I get this issue.
**> eb --version**
EB CLI 3.17.1 (Python 3.7.6)

**> eb deploy my-env**
ERROR: ServiceError - 1 validation error detected: Value '[app-deploy/2020-02-14_16-12-41-4-g87282-200225_225240]' at 'versionLabels' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 100, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1, Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [^/]+]

If I check -staged

**> eb deploy --staged**
ERROR: This branch does not have a default environment. You must either specify an environment by typing "eb deploy my-env-name" or set a default environment by typing "eb use my-env-name".

Answer (score 1):

Try give your version a versionLabel, for example:

`eb deploy my-env -l my-app-v1.3.1`

or

`eb deploy my-env -l "first version of my app"`